# Need help to Write an efficient algorithm function

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, ecmascript-6

Need help with Write an efficient algorithm function:
A small frog wants to get to the other side of the road. The frog is currently located at position X and wants to get to a position greater than or equal to Y. the small frog always jumps a fixed distance, D.

Count the minimal number of jumps that the small frog must perform to reach its target.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int X, int Y, int D); }
```

That, given three integers X, Y and D, returns the minimal number of jumps from position X to a position equal to or greater than Y.

For example, given:

```
X = 10
Y = 85
D = 30
```

The function should return 3, because the frog will be positioned as follows:

- after the first jump, at position 10 + 30 = 40
- after the second jump, at position 10 + 30 + 40 = 70
- after the third jump, at position 10 + 30 + 30 + 30 = 100

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

```
* X,Y and D are integers within the range [1..1,000,000,000];
* X <_ Y.
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you need help to write an algorithm (then it's not a programming question) or do you need help to write a function (do you already have an algorithm)? Both problems are at least two separate questions, probably even more.

Comment: `class Solution { public int solution(int X, int Y, int D); }` isn't JavaScript. It looks like Java.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score -3):

Just subtract X from Y, then divide it by D. If it's a decimal, round it up.

```js
const froggy = (X, Y, D) => Math.ceil((Y - X) / D);

console.log(froggy(10, 85, 30));
```

Comment: IMO, answering requests for free code writing service isn't useful for this platform in the long term. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @jabaa It was more of a math question than anything. Don't punish me for being nice

Comment: But is not a function here.

Comment: @EliranNatan What are you talking about? `froggy` is a function here.

Comment: Not in Java ;-)

Comment: Because the OP doesn't know the difference between JavaScript and Java. Apparently, the answer isn't useful to the OP, too. It doesn't solve the assignment: _"Write a function: `class Solution { public int solution(int X, int Y, int D); }`"_